# How to force gcc generate thumb 32 bit instructions?

Tags: gcc, arm, thumb

Is it possible to force generating thumb 32 bit instructions when possible?

For example I have:

```
int main(void) {
 8000280:   b480        push    {r7}
 8000282:   b085        sub sp, #20
 8000284:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
    uint32_t a, b, c;

    a = 1;
 8000286:   2301        movs    r3, #1
 8000288:   60fb        str r3, [r7, #12]
    b = 1;
 800028a:   2301        movs    r3, #1
 800028c:   60bb        str r3, [r7, #8]
    c = a+b;
 800028e:   68fa        ldr r2, [r7, #12]
 8000290:   68bb        ldr r3, [r7, #8]
 8000292:   4413        add r3, r2
 8000294:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]

    while (1) ;
 8000296:   e7fe        b.n 8000296 <main+0x16>
```

But they are all thumb 16 bit. For testing reason I want thumb 32 bit instructions.

Comment: I thought the whole point of Thumb was that it preferred 16-bit instructions?

Comment: Probably. However I'd like to generate thumb 32 instructions when possible. (Cortex M4)

Comment: I'm not an expert here, I don't even own an ARM processor, but [the guidance I find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638130/what-is-the-arm-thumb-instruction-set) seems pretty clear to me that you are pursuing an impossible task. If you want 32-bit instructions to be emitted, just compile for the standard ARM instruction set. If that isn't satisfactory, consider explaining *why* you are trying to do this, and maybe someone can give you a better workaround.

Comment: If you append `.w` to an instruction it will instruct the compiler to prefer a 32-bit encoding.

Comment: @CodyGray there is a big difference between 32 bit ARM and thumb2 extensions.  As mentioned this is for a cortex-m4 which doesnt support the 32 bit ARM instructions but supports the 140 or so thumb2 extensions (armv7-m).

Comment: First you need to choose between unified syntax or not then use the right command line and/or directive.  See EOFs comment above.  Likewise this has been asked and answered at stack overflow (in various forms).

Comment: If you are compiling high level code (C) and not assembly language then use the proper command line option to select armv7m and/or cortex-m4, it wont always use the larger instructions when there is a choice (this is a microcontroller that would be quite wasteful) but will use it more often than zero times for a decent sized function/project.  GCC is open source so you can look at the backend and see how/when it chooses, you could build your own gcc with perhaps a flag set to lean toward thumb2, or perhaps you will find a command line option.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think you can do that directly, but there is a very strange way of achieving that in a very indirect way. Just a few days ago I've seen a project where the compilation process was not just a simple `arm-none-eabi-gcc ... -c file.c -o file.o`. The project was calling `arm-none-eabi-gcc` to also generate extended assembly listing, which was later assembled manually with `arm-none-eabi-as` into an object file. If you would do it like that, then between these two steps you could modify the assembly listing to have wide instructions only - in most (all?) cases you could just use `sed` to add `.w` suffix to the instructions (change `add r3, r2` into `add.w r3, r2` and so on). Whether or not such level of build complication is worth it, is up to you...